# считывание всего файла через BinaryReader

Tags: c#, binary

Есть бинарный файл, с которого идет чтение побайтно. Как узнать конец файла? Я знаю про метод PeekChar(), но в моем случае он не подходит, потому что я считываю не текст, а сериализованный объект класса. Можно, конечно, знать изначальную длину массива байтов, которая представляла сериализованный объект, но если нет возможности его узнать?

Comment: Покажите ваш код. Как именно вы превращаете байты из файла в объект?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

А почему бы не прочитать файл целиком?

```
byte[] fileBytes = File.ReadAllBytes("...");
```

В этом случае вам нет нужды заботиться о достижении конца файла.

---

Если вам нужно именно с использованием `BinaryReader`, то можно использовать свойства `Position` и `Length` потока данных, из которого он читает:

```
using (var stream  = new FileStream("...", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.Read))
using (var reader = new BinaryReader(stream))
{
    bool endOfStream = stream.Position == stream.Length;
    // Либо:
    // bool endOfStream = reader.BaseStream.Position == reader.BaseStream.Length;
}
```